# Technique(s) to find cyclic vector for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question I am looking is almost **computational** one; for it, we can stick to real vector spaces of finite dimension (say, $3$, $4$ or $5$ is enough).

**Question:** Let $A$ be a real $k\times k$ matrix, whose minimal polynomial is equal to characteristic polynomial. What are tricks/techniques to find out a vector $v$ such that
$$
V=\mbox{span}\,\,\{ v, A(v), \ldots, A^{k-1}(v)\}?
$$

*What problem I am really facing?*

I considered some simple examples of such: if minimal and characteristic polynomials are equal to $(x-6)^2(x-7)^2$, then this means that
$$(A-6I)^2 (A-7I)\neq 0, \hskip5mm (A-6I)(A-7I)^2\neq 0 \hskip5mm \mbox{ but } \hskip5mm (A-6I)^2(A-7I)^2=0.$$
Thus, computing $(A-6I)^2(A-7I)$ and $(A-6I)(A-7I)^2$, since they are non-zero, we can take $v$ to be a vector $v$ not killed by any of them.

This is possible, since unio of kernels of these cubic polynomial matrices in $A$ is not $\mathbb{R}^4$.

But, it this *first-principal way* the only way to proceed for finding cyclic vector, or we can use some techniques? (I am interested in explicit computation.)